# Mysql - Accumulatively count the total on a row by row basis

Tags: mysql, sql, accumulate

I'm trying in MySql to count the number of users created each day and then get an accumulative figure on a row by row basis. I have followed other suggestions on here, but I cannot seem to get the accumulation to be correct.

The problem is that it keeps counting from the base number of 200 and not taking account of previous rows.

[image: Output]

Where was I would expect it to return

[image]

My Sql is as follows;

```
SELECT day(created_at), count(*), (@something := @something+count(*)) as value
FROM myTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @something := 200) r
GROUP BY day(created_at);
```

To create the table and populate it you can use;

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  created_at DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO myTable (created_at) 
            VALUES ('2018-04-01'),
             ('2018-04-01'),
             ('2018-04-01'),
             ('2018-04-01'),
             ('2018-04-02'),
             ('2018-04-02'),
             ('2018-04-02'),
             ('2018-04-03'),
             ('2018-04-03');
```

You can view this on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/730c0a/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT day, cnt, (@s := @s + cnt)
FROM (SELECT day(created_at) as day, count(*) as cnt
     FROM myTable
     GROUP BY day(created_at)
    ) d CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @s := 0) r;
```

`GROUP BY` and variables have not worked together for a long time.  In more recent versions, `ORDER BY` also needs a subquery.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the explanation - that makes more sense! Thanks